# Add up data in a table for a column

Tags: jquery

I have the following table which allows a person to enter data. What I'm trying to do is build a simple function that will work out the totals for each column.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery I have put in place so far is:

```
var total = 0;
// for each table row first cell
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
    // add together the input values of each row
    total += parseInt($(this).find('input').val());
    // find the output for that column (note i think this is where the problem is)
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.output').val(total);
});
```

Doesn't work though. Can anyone help? Thanks very much.

Comment: "Each" acts like a loop , why won't you use "alert" or any tracing method to locate the problem?
For instance , echo the value of total.
Another thing is run the script on Chrome and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col2" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col3" type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col2" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col3" type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" value="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input data-field="col1" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col2" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
            <td><input data-field="col3" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The jQuery:

```
var total = 0;
$('table input[data-field="col1"]:not(.output)').each(function () {
    // add together the input values of each row
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
    $(input[data-field="col1"].output).val(total);
});
```

repeat this for each column, and better yet, create a function that takes in the data-field and call it for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
// for each table row first cell
$('table tbody tr td:first').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($(this).find('input').val());
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.output').val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something to trigger the addition as well:

### The HTML:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="col1 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col2 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col3 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="col1 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col2 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col3 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="col1 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col2 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
                <td><input class="col3 add" type="text" value="100" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="totCol1" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
                <td><input id="totCol2" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
                <td><input id="totCol3" type="text" class="output" value="0" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

### The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    // for each table row first cell
    function calcTotals(){

        console.log("started");
        var total1 = 0;
        var total2 = 0;
        var total3 = 0;

        $('.add').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("col1") == true){
                total1 += parseFloat($(this).val());
                console.log(total1);
            }
            if($(this).hasClass("col2") == true){
                total2 += parseFloat($(this).val());
                console.log(total2);
            }
            if($(this).hasClass("col3") == true){
                total3 += parseFloat($(this).val());
                console.log(total3);
            }
        });



        $("#totCol1").val(total1);
        $("#totCol2").val(total2);
        $("#totCol3").val(total3);
    }

    calcTotals();

    $("input").change(function(){
        calcTotals();
    });
});
```